# CSS3 rhomb to triangle

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I created a rhomb shape by rotating a square 45 degrees:

```
.shape {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Is it possible to animate it into a triangle pointing down by moving the top point down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should define *how* you want it animated.

One possible way

```css
.shape {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, red 50%, transparent 50%);
   background-size: 200%;
   margin: 20px;
   animation: move 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move {
    from {background-position: 100% 100%;}
      to {background-position:  50%  50%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```